# PDO lastInsertID is returning 0

Tags: php, pdo

I am having trouble with lastInsertID returning 0. It is working in another page, so I have something wrong here.

The following is in a try/catch block.

```
$idCount = "42";
/** set the database **/
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name", $db_user, $db_pass);
/** set the error reporting attribute **/
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);            
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT image1 FROM items WHERE `id` = :id");    
/** bind the parameters **/
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $idCount, PDO::PARAM_STR);   
$stmt->execute();                 
$idCount = $db->lastInsertId();
echo $idCount;
```

Comment: if u want to get the max value for id .just do select max(id) from items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function name `->lastInsertId()` should give you a hint that SELECT statements wouldn't normally set the last insert id.

Typically only INSERT statements on tables with an `auto_increment` column exhibit that behaviour.

There are exceptions though, such as when [`LAST_INSERT_ID(expr)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) is used:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(`id`) AS `id`, image1 FROM items WHERE `id` = :id
```

Comment: Very interesting I too was looking for this solution.

Answer (score 2):

`lastInsertId()` will only return the last insert id if you actually do an insert. You are only doing a `select`.

Comment: Ah thanks, is there any way to get the last inserted id without doing an inserting ?

Comment: This is not strictly correct; the last insert id can be populated by other means and not all inserts will set the last insert id value.

Comment: That's false; `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id)` will return the original id in case the key already exists even if there is nothing to update.